# Update rows par lot SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to change a value of column in a table, so I need to do this :

```
update members
set frequence = 1
where frequence <> 1
```

I have 7 million rows impacted, I need to make the update in batches of 100000 rows and then sleep for 2 minutes (time to replications to other datebases).

How can I do this please?

Regrads

Comment: do you have any column to determine order?

Comment: yes I have a memberid

Comment: As soon as you do an update of more than 5000 rows at once, you'll incur a **table-level exclusive lock** (due to SQL Server doing a *lock escalation* to handle the massive number of locks), meaning while that update transaction is running, *no other readers* can even *read* from that table ....

Comment: Do you need a logic in the font-end? Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a somewhat common way to do it, although usually it's used to [limit the impact on transaction logs for large delete operations](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @r INT;
SET @r = 1;

WHILE @r > 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    update top (100000) members
    set frequence = 1
    where frequence <> 1

    SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:02'

    -- To limit log activity:
    -- CHECKPOINT;    -- if simple
    -- BACKUP LOG ... -- if full
END
```

If you need to do them in order, do it like so:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @r INT;
SET @r = 1;

WHILE @r > 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    ;with CTE as (
        select top 100000 *
        from members
        where frequence <> 1
        order by member_id
    )
    update CTE
    set frequence = 1

    SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:02'

    -- To limit log activity:
    -- CHECKPOINT;    -- if simple
    -- BACKUP LOG ... -- if full
END
```

Comment: Why you added transaction? Is it nessasary in such queries?

Comment: @MikhailLobanov No, not in this case.  It's there mainly because of what I copied from.  IMX, it is necessary if you're planning to use it to limit log usage, otherwise CHECKPOINT might not work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @hasRows BIT = 1
WHILE @hasRows = 1
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP (100000) members
    SET frequence=1
    WHERE frequence<>1
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 SET @hasRows = 0

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:02'
END
```

Comment: Should be `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 SET @hasRows = 0`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at Micheal J. Schwartz's article on this very subject:

http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/

It appears that if you are not using memberId to filter on you are going to end up scanning the whole table by the time to get down to the end of the process because frequence is not very selective.

Comment: Ha! "Micheal J. Schwartz" I love it! (Thanks for the plug)